# How to use cut with delimiter " {##} "?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, cut, cat

I have a file that is delimited by `{##}`. I've tried:

```
$ cat infile | cut -d" {##} " -f1 | grep -w "word"
```

but i can't get the `cut` command right. How do I escape special characters (e.g. `!@#$%^&*(){}[]` in `cut`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below command instead of cut and grep:

```
perl -F"{##}" -lane 'print $F[0] if($F[0]=~/\bword\b/)' infile
```

Comment: Did you mean `-F' {##} '`?

Comment: and you also want `/\bword\b/` to correspond with the `grep -w`

Comment: as much as i like `perl`, i must stay i was cheating by calling the bash commands from `python`, so using python to call perl seems weird. Though, i must say the iterations runs much faster on perl =)

Answer (score 3):

First of all `cut` needs single character delimiter (`-d` option). So a string won't work, you need other tool to prepare your input, let's use `sed`.

Secondly you should use single quotes `'` instead of double `"` so it is not interpreted by shell.

This will work if we can use `|` as separator.

```
cat infile | sed 's/ {##} /|/g' | cut -d'|' -f1 | grep -w 'word'
```

You can replace separator `|` with the character that never occurs input file.

---

You can escape shell characters by prefixing them with backslash `\` or putting them in single quotes `'` where they are not interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

awk can also use multi-char separators:

```
awk -F ' {##} ' '$1 ~ /\<word\>/ {print $1}' infile
```